# Combine results from multiple parse.com queries

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

Let's say we're building a blog using Parse.com's javscript sdk where users can follow eachother and have a feed.

The 'Follow' class includes a pointer to the followee & follower.
While the 'Post' class includes a pointer the creator (followee^).

if I now want to fetch all rows inside 'Post' where the creator equals followee and the user equals follower inside the 'Follow' class; then sort them using descending("createdAt"), how would one do that (efficiently)?

I have checked the api reference and there doesn't appear to be a straightforward answer to this issue: https://www.parse.com/docs/js/api/classes/Parse.Query.html

**Any** help is gladly welcome. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be accomplished using a [compound query](https://parse.com/docs/js/guide#queries-compound-queries), specifically [matchesKeyInQuery](https://parse.com/docs/js/api/symbols/Parse.Query.html#matchesKeyInQuery). Compound queries only count as 1 API request.

First, create the *inner* query to find `Follow` objects where the requesting user is a follower.

```
var innerQuery = new Parse.Query("Follow");
innerQuery.equalTo("follower", request.user);
```

Next, create the *outer* query to find `Post` objects where their followee key matches the followee key in the results of our inner query.

```
var outerQuery = new Parse.Query("Post");
outerQuery.descending("createdAt");
outerQuery.matchesKeyInQuery("followee", "followee", innerQuery);
```

This will give you all of the Posts, in descending order by creation date, for all of the "followees" being followed the requesting user.

Cheers,

Russell